# AspectJ aspects ordering

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I have 2 aspects classes with the same point cut, but differences advices. I need to execute   first one and then the other aspect. I can not use Spring "@Ordered" annotation, because I'm use pure aspectJ.

Comment: This is called precedence:
http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-advice.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`@DeclarePrecedence`](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/ataspectj-declare.html)is what you want to use in @AspectJ style, if native syntax is not your coding style of choice.